# Flutter standard WebView request/response debugging values

Tags: flutter, webview

I'm having some issues with the default Flutter `WebView` when loading some pages. So I was wondering if there is a way to actually debug the request/response made by the widget?
Like viewing the headers, params, or other related values that are useful for debugging.

Notice, I'm not willing to update to another widget (like using another plugin), just want to see if there is a way to get a more deep insigs of what's going on behind the scenes when the widget is loading a page.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You know I have problems with payment gateways, I solved it with a Liberia that helped me a lot.

[webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter)

```
  import 'dart:async';
  import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
  class Webview extends StatefulWidget {
    final String url;
    final String titulo;
    const Webview({
      Key key,
      @required this.url,
      @required this.titulo,
    }) : super(key: key);
    @override
    _WebviewState createState() => _WebviewState();
  }
  class _WebviewState extends State<Webview> {
    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
    final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
    bool _loading=false;
    bool _pagado=false;
    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();
      _loading=true;
    }
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return WillPopScope(
        onWillPop: () async {
          if (_pagado){
            Navigator.pop(context, true);
          }
          else{
            Navigator.pop(context);
          }
          return false;
        },
        child: Scaffold(
          key: _scaffoldKey,
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.titulo),
            centerTitle: true,
          ),
          body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                WebView(
                  initialUrl: widget.url,
                  javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                  onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                    _controller.complete(webViewController);
                  },
                  onPageFinished: (String url) {
                    print('Page finished loading: $url');
                    setState(() {
                      _pagado=true;
                      _loading=false;
                    });
                  },
                ),
                Center(child: (_loading)?CircularProgressIndicator():null)
              ],
            );
          })
        ),
      );
    }
  }
```

You call it a normal route